# Problema al generar tablas TH en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un problema al generar los `th` de la siguiente tabla, el código completo consiste en que un profesor asigna notas a sus alumnos, pero como se puede ver en la foto sobran 3 `th`.

Resultado actual :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado esperado :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de como genero la tabla, el problema creo que lo tengo en la linea de `instanceof ExamenTeorico` ya que parece que cuenta todas las instancias creadas del objecto `ExamenTeorico` y imprime ese numero en `th`.

```
public function imprimirAlumnosProfesor($id) {

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Nombre</th>";

    foreach($this->profesores as $key=>$value){

        if($value->getId() == $id){

            foreach($value->materiasAsignadas as $key=>$value){

                foreach($value->alumnosAsignados as $key=>$value){

                    foreach($value->examenesRealizados as $key=>$value){

                        if($value instanceof ExamenTeorico){

                            echo("<th>TEORICO</th>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($this->profesores as $key=>$value){

        if($value->getId() == $id){

            foreach($value->materiasAsignadas as $key=>$value){

                foreach($value->alumnosAsignados as $key=>$value){

                    echo "<td>",$value->getNombre()," ",$value->getApellido()."</td>";

                    foreach($value->examenesRealizados as $key=>$value){

                        if($value instanceof ExamenTeorico){

                            echo "<td>";
                            echo $value->getNota();
                            echo "</td>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                    }
                }
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
}
```

El `var_dump` del la estructura es la siguiente :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Profesor)#11 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["nombre"]=>
    string(9) "Profesor1"
    ["apellido"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["materiasAsignadas"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(Materia)#1 (3) {
        ["nombre"]=>
        string(11) "Matematicas"
        ["alumnosAsignados"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          object(Alumno)#2 (5) {
            ["nombre"]=>
            string(7) "Alumno1"
            ["apellido"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["dni"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["materiasAsignadas"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              *RECURSION*
            }
            ["examenesRealizados"]=>
            array(3) {
              [0]=>
              object(ExamenTeorico)#3 (1) {
                ["nota"]=>
                int(8)
              }
              [1]=>
              object(ExamenTeorico)#4 (1) {
                ["nota"]=>
                int(10)
              }
              [2]=>
              object(ExamenTeorico)#5 (1) {
                ["nota"]=>
                int(3)
              }
            }
          }
          [1]=>
          object(Alumno)#6 (5) {
            ["nombre"]=>
            string(7) "Alumno2"
            ["apellido"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["dni"]=>
            string(1) "2"
            ["materiasAsignadas"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              *RECURSION*
            }
            ["examenesRealizados"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=>
              object(ExamenTeorico)#7 (1) {
                ["nota"]=>
                int(9)
              }
              [1]=>
              object(ExamenTeorico)#8 (1) {
                ["nota"]=>
                int(3)
              }
            }
          }
          [2]=>
          object(Alumno)#9 (5) {
            ["nombre"]=>
            string(7) "Alumno3"
            ["apellido"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["dni"]=>
            string(1) "3"
            ["materiasAsignadas"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              *RECURSION*
            }
            ["examenesRealizados"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              object(ExamenTeorico)#10 (1) {
                ["nota"]=>
                int(3)
              }
            }
          }
        }
        ["profesorAsignado"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          *RECURSION*
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: En todo el objeto hay en efecto 6 exámenes teóricos y tú creas una columna por cada uno de ellos. El problema, creo yo, es la forma en que tienes anidados los datos, que dificulta diferenciar de una forma fácil y clara cuántas columnas va a necesitar la tabla. Quizá convendría organizar la información de una forma más fácil. Yo pienso, dado que estamos en el ámbito de los objetos, ¿acaso no hay una forma de saber cuántos exámenes teóricos impartió el profesor? (en caso de que sea el mismo profesor). Es sólo una idea, tampoco conozco el contexto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque no me gusta como quedaria debido a la estructura que tienes de datos, creo que en tu caso deberias hacer lo siguiente:

1. calcular cuantos examenes ha hecho un alumno, dentro de alumnos
   asignados a una materia asignada al profesor.
2. buscar el total de todos esos examenes. Es el total que realmente
   quieres mostrar como "Teorico" en tu tabla.
3. recorrer un bucle con ese total e imprimir la TH correspondiente.

En tu caso yo haria lo siguiente:

```
$totalExamenesRealizados = 0;
foreach($this->profesores as $key=>$value){

    if($value->getId() == $id){

        foreach($value->materiasAsignadas as $key=>$value){

            foreach($value->alumnosAsignados as $key=>$value){

                $realizadosTeoricos = 0;
                foreach($value->examenesRealizados as $key=>$value){

                    if($value instanceof ExamenTeorico){
                        $realizadosTeoricos++;
                    }
                }
                if($realizadosTeoricos > $totalExamenesRealizados)
                   $totalExamenesRealizados = $realizadosTeoricos;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Una vez hecho esto, en $totalExamenesRealizados tienes el numero de examenes maximos (en tu ejemplo, tendrias 3). Te bastaria entonces hacer un contador e ir imprimiendo los TH:

```
for($cont =0; $cont < $totalExamenesRealizados; $cont++) {
  echo("<th>TEORICO</th>");
}
```

**NOTA:** Por supuesto, coincido con @A. Cedano. Quizas deberias reconsiderar tu array de datos.